# Clang linker issues when installing Distance python library

Tags: python, c, macos, gcc

I'm trying to install [Distance](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Distance/) for python on my mac (OS X Yosemite).

After downloading the package and unpacking it, I run (as described on their page):

```
python setup.py install --with-c
```

From this I get the following error message:

```
running build_ext
building 'distance.cdistance' extension
gcc -fno-strict-aliasing -I/Users/me/anaconda/envs/name/include -   arch x86_64 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I/Users/me/anaconda/envs/name/include/python2.7 -c cdistance/distance.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7/cdistance/distance.o
gcc -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -L/Users/me/anaconda/envs/name/lib -arch x86_64 -arch x86_64 build/temp.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7/cdistance/distance.o -L/Users/me/anaconda/envs/name/lib -o build/lib.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7/distance/cdistance.so
ld: library not found for -lgcc_s.10.5
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

From what I understood from several posts like [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/346377/cannot-find-lgcc-s) or [this previously asked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14118224/clang-linker-issues-from-source-to-gcc-snapshot), it looks like `clang`, which is called through the command `gcc`, can't find the libgcc library.

I ran `find /usr/ -name libgcc*`and this if what I get:

```
/usr//lib/libgcc_s.1.dylib
/usr//lib/libgcc_s.10.4.tbd
/usr//lib/libgcc_s.10.5.tbd
/usr//local/Cellar/gcc/5.2.0/lib/gcc/5/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin14.4.0/5.2.0/i386/libgcc.a
/usr//local/Cellar/gcc/5.2.0/lib/gcc/5/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin14.4.0/5.2.0/i386/libgcc_eh.a
/usr//local/Cellar/gcc/5.2.0/lib/gcc/5/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin14.4.0/5.2.0/libgcc.a
/usr//local/Cellar/gcc/5.2.0/lib/gcc/5/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin14.4.0/5.2.0/libgcc_eh.a
/usr//local/Cellar/gcc/5.2.0/lib/gcc/5/libgcc_ext.10.4.dylib
/usr//local/Cellar/gcc/5.2.0/lib/gcc/5/libgcc_ext.10.5.dylib
/usr//local/Cellar/gcc/5.2.0/lib/gcc/5/libgcc_s.1.dylib
/usr//local/Cellar/gcc/5.2.0/lib/gcc/5/libgcc_s_ppc64.1.dylib
/usr//local/Cellar/gcc/5.2.0/lib/gcc/5/libgcc_s_x86_64.1.dylib
/usr//local/gfortran/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin14/5.1.0/i386/libgcc.a
/usr//local/gfortran/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin14/5.1.0/i386/libgcc_eh.a
/usr//local/gfortran/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin14/5.1.0/libgcc.a
/usr//local/gfortran/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin14/5.1.0/libgcc_eh.a
/usr//local/gfortran/lib/libgcc_ext.10.4.dylib
/usr//local/gfortran/lib/libgcc_ext.10.5.dylib
/usr//local/gfortran/lib/libgcc_s.1.dylib
/usr//local/gfortran/lib/libgcc_s_ppc64.1.dylib
/usr//local/gfortran/lib/libgcc_s_x86_64.1.dylib
```

And now I'm stuck because I don't know what to do next. Basically the question is: how do I make clang to know where the library is ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue thanks to [this link](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/40653) which showed that this is a very recent issue with Xcode6.

You just need to upgrade Xcode to Xcode7 and set it up as your default toolkit chain. Easy.